# How do you upgrade your SharePoint solutions?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I currently support a SharePoint "solution", when I say "solution" I mean a collection of features (like web parts, list definitions and so on) packaged for deployment as a .wsp file. This approach is called the [developers approach](http://hermansberghem.blogspot.com/2009/04/to-package-or-not-to-package-that-is.html) and currently since we give out this .wsp in the form of an MSI, the upgrade process requires the users retract the entire solution and redeploy.

Before I go recreating the wheel with coming up with new ways of upgrading, I wanted to ask SO SharePoint experts for suggestions on how we can mitigate the cumbersome process of retracting a solutions and redeploying for updates/patches while keeping the sharepoint solution store up to date with the latest dlls.

Initial ideas:

- (1) Create a powershell script that automates as many steps as possible, such as retracting the old solution, redeploying the new solution, copying/updating configuration files. Basically redeploying the solution. (Currently used method)
- (2) Have any new patch deployed as a new feature.
- (3) Your ideas/methods here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually do not use .msi installers for deploying SharePoint solutions, largely because I feel like retracting, upgrading, and redeploying solutions is a tad more invasive than necessary for a simple update.

The `stsadm` SharePoint administration tool supports [upgrading a SharePoint solution in-place](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287722%28office.12%29.aspx). The appeal of using `stsadm -o upgradesolution` is that you can avoid retracting, updating, and redeploying code.

On the other hand, the appeal of .msi installers is the double-click-that's-it, no-need-for-a-console installation solution. I try to bridge the gap between the installer experience and the raw `stsadm` experience by drafting up a PowerShell script to handle all the `stsadm` commands, etc.

Upgrade-in-place is usually pretty effective; however, if you plan to make changes to event receiver classes, you may find that a full deactivate-retract-upgrade-deploy-activate cycle is necessary.

For example, I have some WebApplication-scoped features that add new `WebConfigModification` entries to an application's web.config when the feature is activated. Should I add new web.config entries, the new entries will not appear until the feature is deactivated and reactivated.

A reasonable strategy to avoiding the disadvantage above is to implement new features when a change would otherwise force a deactivate-reactivate cycle.

At any rate, there's my two cents on solution deployment strategy. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I often use the script blow using stsadm command to upgrade the WSP package

here are the command with parameters:

```
stsadm -o upgradesolution -name "WSPName.wsp" -filename "c:/WSPName.wsp" -immediate -allowgacdeployment -allowcaspolicies
```

the second command is using for forcing to execute this job immediately

```
stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs
```